# JCR Persistance exception AEM

Tags: aem, jcr, jackrabbit

I have two environments. On one of them everything is working OK on another some magic happens.
I have page with subnode analytics from another resource and when I'm trying to drag and drop any component or edit, some component exception occurs (see stacktrace).
I tried to find resolution in Internet but every problem is specific that's why I'm writing this topic. If I'm deleting analytics node and trying to modify page, it will be modified only once and then I see this exception again.

- First of stack trace:

> Some_date *ERROR* [Some_IP [1450442411491] POST /content/mysubfolder/mypagenode/jcr:content/mycomponent HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.api.resource.PersistenceException: Unable to commit changes to session.
>       at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.commit(JcrResourceProvider.java:638)
>       at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.helper.ResourceResolverContext.commit(ResourceResolverContext.java:181)...

- Second:

> Caused by: javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: OakConstraint0022: /content/mysubfolder/mypagenode/jcr:content/analytics/reportConfigs[[nt:unstructured]]: Mandatory property jcr:primaryType can not be removed
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException.asRepositoryException(CommitFailedException.java:225)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException.asRepositoryException(CommitFailedException.java:212)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.newRepositoryException(SessionDelegate.java:594)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.save(SessionDelegate.java:461)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl$8.perform(SessionImpl.java:435)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl$8.perform(SessionImpl.java:432)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.perform(SessionDelegate.java:216)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:140)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:432)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.apache.sling.jcr.base.SessionProxyHandler$SessionProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(SessionProxyHandler.java:113)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.save(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.commit(JcrResourceProvider.java:636)
>       ... 132 common frames omitted

- Third:

> Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException: OakConstraint0022: /content//mysubfolder/mypagenode/jcr:content/analytics/reportConfigs[[nt:unstructured]]: Mandatory property jcr:primaryType can not be removed
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.nodetype.TypeEditor.constraintViolation(TypeEditor.java:150)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.nodetype.TypeEditor.propertyDeleted(TypeEditor.java:202)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleEditor.propertyDeleted(VisibleEditor.java:85)

Comment: Can you please post the code that is executing the modifications?

Answer (score 1):

The reason if this exception was in given rights to users. We knew that but didn't eve tried to remove rights and give them back in *useradmin* menu. We removed and give rights to group *everyone* and then this issue was fixed.

P.S. AEM it's some kind of magic, remember it!